# Convert jQuery datetimepicker date and time format into a Rails DateTime format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetimepicker, jquerydatetimepicker

I would need to implement jQuery `datetimepicker` into my Ruby on Rails 5 application.
There is good documentation for `jqueryui Date picker`, included two railscasts by Ryan Bates. 
As datetimepicker is concerned, I suppose the only concern about rails is to produce a date and time format that rails can easily understand. Once this issue is solved, I think it is easy to add the plugin to the asset pipeline.

Rails DateTime format is `"yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss"`. For instance `"2017-07-28 11:24:53"`. 
So I wonder: is there any way to change the default `datetimepicker` format into a DateTime rails format ?

In the `datetimepicker` official webpage, the section dedicated to [using another date parser/formatter](http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/#use_other_date_parser) uses as example the `MomentJS` library. However I could not find examples useful for Rails applications.

`jQuery UI Datepicker` has a `dateFormat` option which can be easily used to set the date format to the desired format: how can this be done with `datetimepicker`?

Comment: have you tried the to_datetime method ?

Comment: method `to_datetime` should be used to convert `params[:event][:event_start]` before saving it in the database, and I would not know how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your view :

```
= form_for @event do |f|
  = f.text_field :event_start, class: "datepicker"
```

In your controller

```
def create
  # before the save
  @event.event_start = params[:event][:event_start].to_datetime
end
```

Comment: Since I use `@event = current_user.events.build(event_params)` in the create action, where `event_params` is defined as `params.require(:event).permit(:user_id, :event_start, :place)`, I wonder if I can define `params[:event][:event_start] =  params[:event][:event_start].to_datetime` inside `event_params` before `params.require...`.

Comment: You can achieve that with the date_field form helper : https://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/date_field